# How to use .jar Modules class

Tags: java, log4j, buildpath

I am beginner in Java. I am trying to add a external Library to my existing java module.here is the image in which i am adding libraries.
[image]

this is my LogTest class in which i am trying to print traces of my system. and i am also try to import log4j2 module to my class

```
/**
 * 
 */
package testJavaWeb;

import java.util.Arrays;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;


/**
 * @author root
 *
 */
public class LogTest {

    /**
     * 
     */
    public LogTest() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        System.out.println("Welcome");
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String trace=Arrays.toString(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace());
        System.out.println(trace);
    }

}
```

I am failed to find build path and its giving me error

> import org cannot be resolved

Comment: what's the actual problem. what you're trying to achieve

Comment: i want to write trace of system to json file.